# Hosting/Publishing MVC3 on IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

So to be specific, I'm using a windows server 2003 (that means iis 6). I've already installed ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM and .NET 4.

I've tried a few guides already.I've tried Haacked's guide too, then navigated to the root.

eg.

- localhost/MyWebApp which showed Directory Listing denied (permission related problem probably not relevant to my actual problem).
- Visiting another view, localhost/MyWebApp/Home.mvc/Index, showed 404 error page.

Is there anything I'm missing? I don't have any visual studio installed on the server but should I have used the Web Platform Installer instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app working correctly when you deploy it from visual studio to local IIS?

The "Home.mvc" looks a little odd - with the default routes that would imply a controller named "Home.mvcController", which is not valid.

The other obvious thing to check is that "MyWebApp" is set up as a web application using a .NET 4 app pool rather than just being a directory.

Comment: adding an extension on the global.asax, mapping the extension and hosting it in a .net 4 app pool worked.

Comment: Tom, I'm having the same trouble.  I'm not seeing any way in IIS6 Manager to create an app pool tied to .Net 4.0.  How is this accomplished in IIS 6?